# how to access one pod library into another pod library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, header-files

According to my ScreenShot, I want to access `StepSlider` into `Braintree` pod, but when I try to write `#import <StepSlider/StepSlider.h>` or `#import "StepSlider.h"` into `braintree` header file, it shows me error that " header file is not found"

[image]

So How can I access one pod library into another pod library ?

Please help me. I stucked here. I want to change `braintree` default UI with MY UI So I make changes into main File of `Braintree`

Comment: Why you want to do that? If you modify a pod file then after each "pod install" all your changes in the pods will be gone.

Comment: I want to make custom UI for braintree So, I want that slider into drop-IN-UI of braintree

Comment: I think you should manually include this into your project instead of using pods.

Comment: @bisma If I include those files into project instead pod then I cant access them into braintree pod then pod and my project are likely different among